# javascript adding to beginning and end of innerhtml in a loop

Tags: javascript, append, innerhtml

I have a setInterval and each time through the loop I want to add something to the beginning and end of the text in a div. Lets say I want to add the letter "x".  I only know how to add to the end like this...

```
t=setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML +='x'
},1000)
```

Lets say the loop runs 10 times before I clear the interval, my text would look like,

My Textxxxxxxxxxx

I want it to look like

xxxxxxxxxxMy Textxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: `document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="x"+document.getElementById('test').innerHTML +'x';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
var tmpStr = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
tmpStr = 'a' + tmpStr + 'a';
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = tmpStr;
```

Answer (score 1):

use the contents of the element directly

```
t=setInterval(function(){
  var contents = document.getElementById('test').innerHtml
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'x' + contents + 'x'
},1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Should just be able to save off the innerHTML:

```
t = setInterval(function(){
  var el = document.getElementById('test');
  var text = el.innerHTML;
  el.innerHTML = 'x' + text + 'x';
},1000)
```

Incidentally . . . this seems like a weird thing to want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
t=setInterval(function(){
var D = document.getElementById('test');
    D.innerHTML = "x"+D.innerHTML+"X";
},1000)
```